# Redis Escape Special Character

Tags: redis

How we can escape special characters in Redis search? I am sscan using to search for data from Redis using Match operation and my data having a special character in it like @#[]$& etc so How I can do it?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function to escape characters on when inserting to redis. I believe all you need to do is add an extra slash to the replacement value when you're replacing a search value.

```
function redisReplace(value) {
const replacements = {
    ',': '\\,', 
    '.': '\\.',
    '<': '\\<',
    '>': '\\>',
    '{': '\\{',
    '}': '\\}',
    '[': '\\[',
    ']': '\\]',
    '"': '\\"',
    "'": "\\'",
    ':': '\\:',
    ';': '\\;',
    '!': '\\!',
    '@': '\\@',
    '#': '\\#',
    '$': '\\$',
    '%': '\\%',
    '^': '\\^',
    '&': '\\&',
    '*': '\\*',
    '(': '\\(',
    ')': '\\)',
    '-': '\\-',
    '+': '\\+',
    '=': '\\=',
    '~': '\\~',
}

const newValue = value.replace(/,|\.|<|>|\{|\}|\[|\]|"|'|:|;|!|@|#|\$|%|\^|&|\*|\(|\)|-|\+|=|~/g, function(x) {
        return replacements[x]
})
return newValue
}
```

Comment: Good answer!! But I am wondering if C#, serviceStack or Redis itself have a built in function to escape these special chars. Does anyone knows?